# Odd rendering of an html table in Ruby on Rails when using content_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, content-tag

I'm trying to build a table in Ruby on Rails with the help of the content_tag method.

When I run this:

```
def itemSemanticDifferential(method, options = {})

  if options[:surveyQuestion].any? then
    @template.content_tag(:tr) do
      @template.content_tag(:td, options[:surveyQuestion], :colspan => 3)
    end
  end

  @template.content_tag(:tr) do
    @template.content_tag(:th, options[:argument0])
  end
end
```

Only the second part gets rendered:

```
@template.content_tag(:tr) do
  @template.content_tag(:th, options[:argument0])
end
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Ruby Rails returns the last variable it used if no `return` is called. If you want to return both, use an Array `results = []` and add them like this: `results << @template.content_tag(:tr) do #...`

Comment: Does this solution works for you?

Comment: actually it does work on some level, but the elements now dont get rendered so it looks smth. like this: <tr><td colspan="3">any smart question</td></tr><tr><th>left</th></tr>

Comment: What do you mean by "dont get rendered"? Read my warning in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby Rails returns the last variable it used if no return is explicitly called.
( example: )

```
def some_method(*args)
  a = 12
  b = "Testing a String"
  # ...
  3
end # This method will return the Integer 3 because it was the last "thing" used in the method
```

Use an Array to return all the content_tag (**WARNING**: this method will return an Array, not a content_tag as you expect, you'll need to loop on it):

```
def itemSemanticDifferential(method, options = {})

  results = []

  if options[:surveyQuestion].any? then
    results << @template.content_tag(:tr) do
      @template.content_tag(:td, options[:surveyQuestion], :colspan => 3)
    end
  end

   results << @template.content_tag(:tr) do
    @template.content_tag(:th, options[:argument0])
  end

  return results # you don't actually need the return word here, but it makes it more readable
end
```

As asked by author of the Question, You need to loop on the result because it is an array of content_tags. Also, you need to use `.html_safe` to output the content_tags as HTML (not strings).

```
<% f.itemSemanticDifferential(:method, options = {}).each do |row| %>
  <%= row.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you but as stated above this produces smth. like this:  <tr><td colspan="3">any smart question</td></tr><tr><th>left</th></tr>

Comment: What should it produces? It produces what you tell him to produce. If you want to have 2 explicit table row, you have to loop on the result of `itemSemanticDifferential`

Comment: oh sorry i skipped this (long hours!! ;))).. im new to ruby, what do you mean by looping on it?

Comment: The returned object is an Array containing max 2 items. You need to do a `each` statement on the result of `itemSemanticDifferential`

Comment: im calling the function with: <%= f.itemSemanticDifferential :method, {:buttonCount => 5, :surveyQuestion => "any smart question", :argument0 => "left", :argument1 => "right"} %> --ive read about the each statement but i only find stuff referencing to smth. like: >> method.each

Comment: Try the following: `<% f.itemSemanticDifferential(:method, {:buttonCount => 5, :surveyQuestion => "any smart question", :argument0 => "left", :argument1 => "right"}).each do |row| %><%= row.html_safe %><% end %>`

Comment: Great :) I'm glad it works fine for you! Have fun with Rails ;)